# Aggregate by week using (Sun - Sat)

Tags: sql, presto

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CAST(WEEK(CAST(date as DATE)) as VARCHAR), ' - WEEK') as week,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(field1)) as field1_count,
    SUM(amount) as amount
FROM table
WHERE SUBSTR(DATE, 1, 4) = '2020'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

---

Is there a way to ensure that the aggregate here is `Sun - Sat`? This is currently aggregating at `Mon - Sun`

Answer (score 1):

Add one day to the date:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(WEEK(CAST(date + INTERVAL '1' DAY as DATE)) as VARCHAR), ' - WEEK') as week,
```

Comment: Correct syntax for presto `CONCAT(CAST(WEEK(CAST(processing_payment_date as DATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY) as VARCHAR), ' - WEEK') as week`. The worst feeling when you overlook the simple solution. Thank you